# Custom layer using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, model, customization, layer

I am trying to make customized layer which reduces channels by reduce_sum(axis=-1)

For example when input shape is (32,32,128)

> I want to change the input shape from (32,32,128) to (None,32,32,128) and

And if the channels have index which will be like [0],[1],[2],[3]………[126],[127]
And my customized layer want to do is adding 2or 3 or 4…N channels

Lets say if i want to add only 2 channels
Whoch will be [0]+[1],[1]+[2]….[126]+[127]
And the output shape will be (32,32,64)

> also (None,32,32,64)

For more details lets say i want to add 3 channels which will be [0]+[1]+[2],[3]+[4]+[4]… … [123]+[124]+[125],[126]+[127]
And the output shape will be (32,32,44)

> Here too (None,32,32,44)

So is it possible to make it?

Is there index in channels? If so it would be kinda easy to make it I think…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = tf.random.normal(shape=(32,32,128))
    sum_dim = 2
    x = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1], -1, sum_dim)), -1)
    #[32, 32, 64]
```

If you want to write the keras layer:

```
class ChannelSum(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, sum_dim=2):
        super(ChannelSum, self).__init__()
        self.sum_dim = sum_dim
    def call(self, x ):
        return tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[3]//self.sum_dim, self.sum_dim)), -1)
```

Comment: what if the input shape is (none,32,32,128)?
i was trying tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(x,(-1,x.shape[1],x.shape[2],x.shape[3],sum_dim)),-1), 
But it doesn't reduce the channel number.

my input shape was (None,4,4,384) and the result is 

 max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPoolin  (None, 4, 4, 384)        0         
 g2D)        
 tf.reshape_4 (TFOpLambda)   (None, 4, 4, 384, 2)      0         
                                                                 
 tf.math.reduce_sum_6 (TFOpL  (None, 4, 4, 384)        0         
 ambda)

Comment: thank you so much I have gained some insights. But what if the input shape is (None,32,32,128)? @vijayachandranmariappan

Comment: Also, normally, I'm not used to adding one more parameter such as sum_dim... can you explain how the 4th argument(sum_dim) works? does it add up as I asked? @vijayachandranmariappan

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It helped me perfectly as I the way I wanted.